# Vue js: How to use a computed property to modify string and apply dynamically as CSS class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am following a tutorial and I want to add a new feature where the surname of each candidate is added as a class. I got this to work inline but then I wanted to clean it up and rather call it as a function.

**Working inline**

```
mayor.name.replace(/ /g,'').replace('Mr.','').toLowerCase()
```

The function `textClass` removes spaces and "Mr." from the string. I've tried adding this as a computed property but I don't know how to call it on `mayor.name`

**CSS**

```
.black{ color: black;}
.brown{ color: brown;}
.pink{ color: pink;}
.red{ color: red;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="mayor-vote">
    <h2>Mayor Vote</h2>
    <ul class="list-group" style="width: 400px;">
      <li v-for="candidate in candidates" class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <strong style="display: inline-block; width: 100px;">{{ candidate.name }}:</strong> {{ candidate.votes }}
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" @click="candidate.votes++">Vote</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Our Mayor is <span class="the-winner" :class="mayor.name.textClass">{{ mayor.name }}</span></h2>
    <button @click="clear" class="btn btn-default">Reset Votes</button>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
 new Vue({

  el: '#mayor-vote',

  data: {
    candidates: [
      { name: "Mr. Black", votes: 140 },
      { name: "Mr. Red", votes: 135 },
      { name: "Mr. Pink", votes: 145 },
      { name: "Mr. Brown", votes: 140 }
    ]
  },

  computed: {
    mayor: function(){
      var candidateSorted = this.candidates.sort(function(a,b){
        return b.votes - a.votes;
      });
      return candidateSorted[0];
    },
    textClass: function() {
      return this.replace(/ /g,'').replace('Mr.','').toLowerCase();
    }
  },

  methods: {
    clear: function() {
      this.candidates = this.candidates.map( function(candidate){
        candidate.votes = 0;
        return candidate;
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code, one is [dynamic class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) in vue takes a hash object, not an string. So you have to return an hash like this : `{ active: true }` from the computed property.

Second thing is [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) in vue always modify another vue propery or values returned from an mehtod, to correct these you need to make following changes:

You have to use `this.mayor.name` in computed property to calculate dynamic class like this:

```
  computed: {
    mayor: function(){
      var candidateSorted = this.candidates.sort(function(a,b){
        return b.votes - a.votes;
      });
      return candidateSorted[0];
    },
    textClass: function() {
      var tmp = {}
      tmp[this.mayor.name.replace(/ /g,'').replace('Mr.','').toLowerCase()] = true
      return tmp
    }
  },
```

and apply like this in HTML:

```
<h2>Our Mayor is <span class="the-winner" :class="textClass">{{ mayor.name }}</span></h2>
```